# Getting the error: "Reading from _value directly is only possible on the UI runtime" when trying to use the react-native-animated library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

Tried going to other stack threads, found nothing helpful.

Here is my code:

```
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function Screen() {

 const padding1 = useSharedValue(0);
 const padding2 = useSharedValue(0);

 useEffect(() => {
  padding1.value = 0;
  padding2.value = 0;
  setTimeout(() => padding1.value = withSpring(padding1.value+hp(5)), 100);
  setTimeout(() => padding2.value = withSpring(padding2.value+hp(5.5)), 300);
 }, []);

 return (
  <View className="bg-white/20 rounded-full" style={{padding: padding2}}>
        <View className="bg-white/20 rounded-full" style={{padding: padding1}}>
            <Image source={require('../../assets/welcome.png')}
                    style={{width: hp(20), height: hp(20)}}/>
        </View>
  </View>
 )
}
```

Issue seems to arise when I input the padding1 and padding2 into my return statement

Would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Animated` component from `react-native-reanimated` to make it work and not the default component from React Native.

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

// And then in your code

<Animated.View className="bg-white/20 rounded-full" style={{padding: padding2}}>
...
</Animated.View>
```

You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/core/createAnimatedComponent) to learn more.